# Nativescript http fcm integration

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I am having trouble sending a message to fcm using nativescript fcm plugin and http, I was successful using chromes arc app. Can someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the post function :

```js
exports.postExt = function(URL, headerName, headerValue, message){
    console.log("PostingEXT to " + URL);
    http.request( 
        {url: URL,
        method: "POST",
        headers: { headerName: headerValue,
                "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        content: JSON.stringify({"to" : "/topics/" +            message.getTopic()})}).then(function (response) {
            console.log("Done!");
        }, function (e) {
            getError(error);
        });
}
```

Here is where I use it(Typescript):

```js
private static FIREBASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    private static API_KEY = "key=MY_REAL_API_KEY_IS_HERE";

private static sendDataToFirebase(message : FirebaseMessage<any>){
        Restfull.postExt(this.FIREBASE_URL, "Authorization", this.API_KEY, message);
    }
```

If someone can help me, I would be really thankful. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I still have not figured this out...